# Python Tkinter - I'm having black rectangles while loading window using custom theme

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to create custom theme for `ttk`, for that I tried using full `python` and `tcl` but with both I have same problem, for few seconds when I open window/reopen with taskbar widgets with customs images are black. How can I avoid that or improve it?
Thanks!

[image: bugged image]

[image: normal image]

Comment: how did you manage to create that without any code? did you use some Graphical placement of the different items?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki nowhere does it say no code was used. Maybe you're passive-aggressively saying that the code needs to be shared, though, in which case you should just ask for a [mre]...

Comment: I used .pack() method on all widgets, you seems right because with .place() method this is not happenning. I think I will have to use .grid() since it's faster. Thanks

Comment: Since for create minimal example I need 3 files it's not very useful, and not sure it will help.

Comment: if it's 3 files then is reproducible but not minimal. minimal means a few lines of code that create one single checkbutton that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I can't show because for get that I use assets + python file + tcl file